# Trouble Loading Images in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, swift2

I'm trying to put images into my `UITableView`. The Table is set up with a custom subclass cell. In the Subclass I have outlets:

`@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!`

```
`@IBOutlet var pillarIcon: UIImageView!`
```

In the Superclass I created a `NSMutableArray` for both:

```
var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

var imageObjects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

I place things into the Arrays within the `viewDidLoad` Method Each array has 4 items.

So when I call the Items:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.objects.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = self.objects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String

    cell.pillarIcon.image = self.imageObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage


    return cell


}
```

The `cell.titleLabel.text` items come up but the images in the `cell.pillarIcon.image` do not come show up in the table.

I have been working on this for a couple hours now and am going in circles it feels like. Also the image files have been loaded into the main file so that is not the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried being more specific with your array types? Try:

var objects = [UIImage]()
var imageObjects = [String]()

Comment: How are you loading your images values in the `imageObjects` property?

Comment: @whyceewhite I'm loading the images like so: `self.imageObjects.addObject("book.jpg")`
        `self.imageObjects.addObject("bookmark.png")`

Comment: Check if `self.imageObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage` is returning nil. If not, the problem is on your custom table cell.

Comment: Can you try cell.pillarIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Demo.png"). for conformation.

Comment: @alaphao I agree I believe it is returning nil even though I loaded the objects into the array.

Comment: @vipulk617 I have tried that and it does work but puts one image in for every row.

Comment: @Rico try this to make sure: `let x = self.imageObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIImage; print("x = \(x)")` and show me what is being printed in the console.

Comment: @alaphao                                                                                                        `x = nil`                                                                                                             `x = nil`                                                                                                           `x = nil`                                                                                                            `x = nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your images are loaded into your `Images.xcassets` and then use the `UIImage(name:)` method to load the images.

---

Currently, you are loading your images into your `imageObjects` array as follows:

```
self.imageObjects.addObject("book.jpg")
```

You are not using the `UIImage` to load the image.

Once your images are a part of your project's image assets (`Images.xcassets`), load your images like so:

```
self.imageObjects.addObject(UIImage(named: "book"))
```

(The above example assumes that `book` is the name of the image asset group.)

Note, this [Adding Image Assets](http://guides.codepath.com/ios/Adding-Image-Assets) web page has instructions on how to set up an image asset group.

Comment: Thanks for the information I will try this out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are loading images incorrectly, like @whyceewhite said in his answer.

I will try to make it clear to you:

1. open Assets.xcassets

[image: xcassets]

2. Drop all images you want to use under `AppIcon`
   [image: xcassets2]
3. Add images to your array this way:

`imageObjects.addObject(UIImage(named: "whiteboardapp")!)`

Use the same name displayed on Assets.xcassets folder

Comment: This works I was actually working on what whyceewhite's suggestion when we were going back and forth. I appreciate the help. Quick question though. It appears I can load the image just by writing `imageObjects.addObject(UIImage(name: "book.jpg") !)` this is written without putting it in the Assets.xcassets. Is there any downside to leaving it out of the .xcassets?

Comment: The use .xcassets is the recommended way to deal with assests such as images. It has many features that you can take benefit. You can check all the features here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html